Clear cutting fine whiskers of bird in Photoshop CC
Am wondering what the best way to clear cut around a bird that has thin whiskers around its face? I am trying to use the refine edge brush tool with a hardness of around 32% but its cutting too much away and looks too feathered. Is there a better method?

